# $sce and ng-bind-html not working?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

guys!

I am using Angular 1.4.3 and trying to get some html pasted from the user to be embedded in the page (a google map share link). What I've got is, in my controller I am getting the value and running it trough $sce:

```
$scope.schoolData.trustedGoogleMapsLink = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.schoolData.google_maps_link);
```

and then binding it to a html element using:

```
<p ng-bind-html="schoolData.trustedGoogleMapsLink.toString()"></p>
```

but nothing appears. There is no error, nothing. When I don't run the html trough $sce, I get an error saying it's not sanitized.

Anyone had this problem before? Following Angulars docs example, this should work ...

**Edit:**

I have actually pasted the wrong version of the code. When using the .toString() method, it returns an error that it's not sanitized. When removing the .toString() method, there's just nothing displaying in the paragraph ...

Comment: Have you included the `ngSanitize` module?

Comment: You dont have to do `.toString()` right? Just `<p ng-bind-html="schoolData.trustedGoogleMapsLink"></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
<p ng-bind-html="schoolData.trustedGoogleMapsLink"></p>
```

trustAsHtml returns an object which ng-bind-html understands.